# What is esp's value after these instructions are executed?

Tags: reverse-engineering

If the esp register has the value 0xbfffee34 at the beginning of this sequence of instructions, what is esp's value after these instructions are executed? Assume that we are using standard 32-bit x86 linux calling conventions.

```
8049860: add $0x44, %esp

8049863: pop %ebx

8049864: pop %esi

8049865: pop %ebp

8049866: ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `pop` instruction will increment `esp` by 4 on x86, and the `ret` instruction will pop the caller's `eip` from the stack, thus also incrementing `esp` by 4.

So the value of `esp` after these instructions will be

`ESP = 0xbfffee34 + 0x44 + 0x4 + 0x4 + 0x4 + 0x4 = 0xbfffee88`